# Populate UI once data finishes loading

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am fetching data from a server, and I would like to do this every time the user enters the screen. The problem is, I start getting the data when the screen function is called, and apparently there isn't enough time to fetch the data before the screen is populated. What I am trying now is something like:

```
function MyScreen() {
    model.refreshData();
    const data = model.getData();
    return (<View><Text>{data}</Text></View>);
}
```

This does not work, because, again, data has not been refreshed by the time that we do the "getData". I can't use a `.then`, because then I won't be able to return the `(<View><Text>{data}</Text></View>)` part. Is there a way that I can force the screen to update once `model.refreshData()` has finished?

Comment: The basic scenario will place a loading indicator until you fetch data & after that display data. check this example provide by react-native  - https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't work for me. React navigation does not use Components, and instead uses singular functions for the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use reactive state to change the return value of `MyScreen` when the data is done loading. The following is pseudocode:

```
function MyScreen() {
    const [screenData, setScreenData] = useState(null);
    model.refreshData();
    setScreenData(model.getData());

    // Component will render nothing until data is finished loading
    if (!screenData) {
      return null;
    }

    // Once data is loaded your full component will render
    return (<View><Text>{screenData}</Text></View>);
}
```

If `getData()` is a promise then instead of

```
setScreenData(model.getData());
```

do

```
model.getData().then((data) => setScreenData(data));
```

Comment: What are `setScreenData` and `useState` exactly?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `setParams`?

Comment: It's how to use component states in functional components https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html